# I want to link to another page with this code with the id get from the current page

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, eclipse

I am not sure why I can't link to another page. The error from `logcat` was a syntax error. Can anybody help? Thank You

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $("#forumtable").append("<tr><td>" + "<b>Topic: </b>" + arr[i].topic_name + "<b><br>Content: </b>"
        + arr[i].topic_content + "<b><br>Date: </b>" + arr[i].topic_date + "<b><br>By: </b>" + arr[i].topic_creator 
        + "<b><br>Total Views: </b>" + arr[i].topic_views + "</td><td><a href='#' class='ui-btn' onClick=window.location='forumdetails.html?topic_id=" + arr[i].topic_id + " &cat_id=" + arr[i].cat_id + "'>View </a></tr><br><br>");
}
```

Comment: onClick=  << this is your problem you don't open and close your onclick, you might need to do somthing like '+"'"+'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've quotes issue, you could add escaped double quotes `\"` arround `onclick` :

```
... onClick=\"window.location='forumdetails.html?topic_id="+arr[i].topic_id+" &cat_id="+arr[i].cat_id+"'\">View ...
```

Hope this helps.